# Having some problem trying to troubleshoot my code on an assignment on python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been attempting this assignment but I've encountered a few problems which I am still unable to resolve. Firstly, I am unable to collect the correct sum of numbers from the text so my average value is very off. Secondly, for line 14 it does feel quite strange to have to define my sum as a string before changing it back to float, although it does not give me a Traceback. Lastly, the questions states to not use the sum() function but I'm having trouble not using it. If possible, I would like to understand what is the rationale behind the question restricting us from using the sum() function.

Some help would be greatly appreciated!

file name: https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt , input should be mbox-short.txt

P.S : I added the count as the final output just to see how many lines did it register.

Assignment :

Write a program that prompts for a file name, then opens that file and reads through the file, looking for lines of the form:

X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475

Count these lines and extract the floating point values from each of the lines and compute the average of those values and produce an output as shown below. Do not use the sum() function or a variable named sum in your solution.
You can download the sample data at http://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt when you are testing below enter mbox-short.txt as the file name.

```
fname =input("Enter file name: ")
fhand = open(fname)
for lx in fhand :
    if not lx.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") :
        continue
    ly = lx.replace("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"," ")
    ly = ly.strip()
def avg():
    sum = 0
    count = 0
    count = count
    for values in ly :
        count = count + 1
        sum = str(sum) + values
    return print("Average spam confidence:", count, float(sum) / count)
avg()
```

Comment: Can you give more info about the 'fname' and it's contents?
By the way, the assignment link which you have provided says Session Expired.

Comment: Sorry! I've edited it. It should be fine right now

Comment: Line number 7 is where you have the floating point number which is required. Store each of these numbers into a list and iterate over this list to find the sum and average

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes with your code. Store each float numbers into a list and iterate over this list when you perform addition operation to find the total sum.

```
fname =input("Enter file name: ")
fhand = open(fname)
num_list = []
for lx in fhand :
    if not lx.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") :
        continue
    ly = lx.replace("X-DSPAM-Confidence:","")
    num_list.append(float(ly))
def avg():
    total = 0
    count = 0
    for values in num_list:
        count = count + 1
        total += values
    return print("Average spam confidence:", count, total / count)
avg()
```

Output:

```
Average spam confidence: 27 0.7507185185185187
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked For Me

```
summition = 0
fname =input("Enter file name: ")
count = 0
fhand = open(fname)
for lx in fhand :
    if not lx.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") :
        continue
    ly = lx.replace("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"," ")
    ly = ly.strip()
    summition += float(ly)
    count = count + 1
fhand.close()

print("Average Spam " + str(count)+ " " +  str(summition/count))
```

Bad Code Hints :-

- Always Close File Handle
- return print() // Returns None